# Установить фон кнопке в виде xml файла

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне можно присвоить фон кнопке фон в виде xml файла

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Программный:

   `findViewById(R.id.button).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);`
2. В xml разметке:

`<Button
....
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
....
    />`